# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java

Hello I am new to Java and this is my first program of java with arrays. I am not able to figure out how to fix `Indexoutofbound` error.
I am searched on the net its pretty common issue but I am not able to figure out what causing it here in my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at threeDArrays.main(threeDArrays.java:14)
```

I have three dimensional array with size 3,4,5 respectively and filling up it with three loops with same 3,4,5 size condition. I am not able to understand despite the loops don't overflow why it is giving `Indexoutofbound` error? I have following code.

```
class threeDArrays
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int threeD [][][] = new int[3][4][5];
        int i,j,k;

        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<5; j++)
                {
                    threeD [i][j][k] = i*j*k;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<5; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(threeD [i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this lines `for(k=0; k<5; j++)` you have a counter `k`, but you add one to `j`

Change this line in both places you have it:

```
for(k=0; k<5; j++)
```

to:

```
for(k=0; k<5; k++)
// -----------^
```